# Function pointer different behaviour in GCC and Arduino

Tags: c, gcc, arduino

In my C program I have a skeleton for a command interpreter. It works fine on Linux/GCC, but in Arduino it does not return the expected results.

Below find the PC code. I did the appropriate changes for Arduino, and it works except the return string (see second line from bottom in listing).

C-Code on PC (working):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* help(char *s){
  char *helpString="This is the help string\n";
  return helpString;
}

typedef struct {
  const char* command;
  char* (*cmdExec)(char *s);
}S_COMMAND;


S_COMMAND cmdTable[]= {
   {"he", help}
};

int main(void){
    char *text;

    printf("\n%s\t",cmdTable[0].command); // returns "he"

    text = (cmdTable[0].cmdExec)("0");
    /* returns help string on PC as expected, but garbage on Arduino */

    printf("\n%s", text);
}
```

Comment: This sounds like some AVR Harvard architecture issue more than anything else. Probably there's some non-standard tweak to allow it to read string literals. One of many reasons not to use these old 8-bitters.

Comment: The code looks correct to me, but just to be sure: try declaring `char *helpString="This is the help string\n";` as a global variable. Also try to call `help` directly (`text = help("0");`) and see what happens then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice. I modified the code like follows (peeking at Node.JS), and it is working fine now on both platforms.

```
int help(char *req, char *res){
  strcpy(res, "This is the help string...\n");
  return 0;
}

typedef struct {
  char* command;
  int (*cmdExec)(char *request, char *result);
}S_COMMAND;

S_COMMAND cmdTable[]= {
  {"he", help}
};

int main(void){
    char text[20];

    cmdTable[0].cmdExec("0", text);
}
```

Comment: Watch out for the string length: you break the buffer you passed. Can you put the help string (pointer) into the `struct`?

Comment: Thanks, but the buffer was for reference here only. Anyway, I know I have to obey the buffer length.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid C code (with the exception of the missing `return` statement in `main`), and a conforming C compiler should accept it and produce a working executable. In particular, your use of function pointers isn’t related to the problem at hand. Furthermore, the manual for avr-gcc does not mention any relevant restrictions. I don’t have an Arduino on hand to test the behaviour but if avr-gcc does not produce working code for the input you’ve shown then this suggests a bug in the compiler.

Answer (score -3):

```
char* help(char *s){
  char *helpString="This is the help string\n";
  return helpString;
}
```

You're returning a local variable - it ceases to exist once you go out of scope from the function. That it works at all on any platform is pure luck as once it ceases to exist, trying to access the string is undefined behaviour.

Comment: IMO `"This is the help string\n";` is a string literal and not a local variable and therefore should not go out of scope.

Comment: It would be a local variable if it was declared like `char helpString[] = "This is the help string\n";`

Comment: The local variable is irrelevant. It is functionally equivalent to `return "This is the help string\n";`